# Can I search for "A*" on stack overflow?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I'm trying to look up stuff on A* search. The search box doesn't really help, it seems to ignore the *, which of course makes the search a little less precise. I know that I can successfully search for C#, so it seems not out of the realm of possibility.

Comment: Probably one of those weird use cases... I tried astar, a-star, and the tag a-star works.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a-star

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As snicker pointed out, the questions involving A* are tagged as <kbd>a-star</kbd>.

Try searching for

> [a-star]

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's true. But I don't need to search for [c-sharp]!

Answer (score 1):

if you can't search for it on Google, it's unlikely we will be able to find it either.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the [latest search engine changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange), you can now search for terms containing symbols by using quotes.  For example, you can [search for "A*"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22A*%22)